# selecting individuals in long format in r

Tags: r

I have a data with 100 patients and each patient has values from 7 days (1 to 7). How can I select only patients according another variable only in day 1?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
             day = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
             RRT = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0))

id    day   RRT
1      1     0
1      2     1
1      3     0
2      1     1 
2      2     0
2      3     0
```

I want select only id whom had RRT at day = 0.

Comment: A snippet of real code might be helpful

Comment: Can you show us desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways, for example by using the `filter` function within `dplyr`. Assuming you want all ids if RRT does not equal 0 and day equals 1:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
filter(day == 1 & RRT != 0)

id day RRT
2   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `data.table`:-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df <- df[day == 1 & RRT != 0, ]

   id day RRT
1:  2   1   1
```