# filter id in cluster according another variable in R

Tags: r, project

I have a data with 100 patients and each patient has values from 7 days (1 to 7). How can I select only patients according another variable only in day 1?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
         day = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
         RRT = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

I want select only id whom had `RRT=0` at `day = 1`.

Comment: Fixed formatting for improved readability.

Comment: Can you pls show us the desired output based on your sample data? (BTW- asking multiple [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925572/selecting-individuals-in-long-format-in-r) might not help. You may need to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) link and update your question properly)

Comment: The desired output id=c(1,1,1), day c(1,2,3), RRT=c(0,1,0) and all the others colunms  I had been omitted for space.

Answer (score 0):

When using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(day == 1 & RRT == 0) %>% 
  select(id)
```

or base R:

```
df[df$day == 1 & df$RRT ==0,"id"]
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option gave me all ids. How can I filter all my table only with these ids? I have more than 45000 different ids. Best

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subset function in base R:

```
subset(df,RRT==0&day==1)
```

if you only need the `id` column the you can select

```
with(df,id[RRT==0&day==1])
```

Comment: but this will select the individuals after day 2 in first column that received RRT in day 1.

Comment: This gives a dataframe, not a vector, And it cannot give for anyother day apart from day==1